# How do I get a bank account without a person number?

Tags: banking, sweden

I've just been to the Skatteverket to apply for a personnummer. Apparently it can take 6 weeks. I need a bank account a lot more urgently than that. Where can I go?

I have a contract for a permanent Swedish job and my British (Non-nordic EU) passport.

Answer (score 3):

## Go to SEB

**Today's walking adventure:**
Went to SEB (in Tegnérgatan), told I couldn't open an account. Handelsbanken, ditto. Same again at Nordea. **Turned up at the Odenplan branch of SEB and opened an account without difficultly**.

I opened a [private account](http://seb.se/privat/betala/konton/privatkonto) with a [Maestro card](http://seb.se/privat/betala/kort/maestro) without the ability to buy  things online (card fee of 15kr per month).

They looked at my passport and work contract. I don't know whether the second was essential. I don't know how this would have played differently if I wasn't an EU citizen.

I never tried Swedbank, I'm still a bit confused by the initial rejection at SEB and things may have changed since August 2016, so please do give answers with your own experiences.

Comment: It's probably a combination of bank and branch

Comment: I've been told that the banks the said no weren't exactly comping with Swedish law [on deposits](https://www.riksdagen.se/sv/dokument-lagar/dokument/svensk-forfattningssamling/lag-19951571-om-insattningsgaranti_sfs-1995-1571) (ie they have to take everyone's money), and the "Prohibition of discrimination on grounds of
nationality" rule of the EU. But not that this matters, I don't do legal arguments in bank branches. It may help to gently point this out though. Personally, I'm 2 years in and still happy with SEB. Some of these branches no longer exist, Tegnérgatan for sure (#karma).